# php | Cut string bug

Tags: php

I'm trying to cut my string. But this string is highlighted!

**Example:** `This is my long long <span style="color:#FF0000;">nice</span> string!`

I'm trying to cut my string using the function below:

```
static function cut($string, $max = 255){

        $string = mb_ucfirst(trim($string), 'UTF-8');

        if(mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8') >= $max){
           $string = mb_substr($string, 0, $max - 5, 'UTF-8').'...';
        } return $string;
}
```

And sometimes after cutting my string I'm getting:

```
This is my long long <span style="color:#FF0
```

This breaks my layout... How can I fix my cut function (Correct **$max** value with first `</span>`) to avoid this issue?

Comment: First cut the string to the end of the span tag. I

Comment: Your probably want to look at using DOM manipulation here.  That would allow you to easily see if there was nested HTML elements inside the element you are wanting to cut, allowing you to extract the text from that element.